# MySQL server version issue

Tags: php, sql

i building simple WebService for my web app which contain only two php files **connecttodatabase.php** contain the code of mysql connection and **index.php** contain the code of my webService but i got sql error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**desc, cat, price FROM itmes**' at line 3

**connecttodatabase.php**

```
<?php
$requesturi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pos = strpos($requesturi, "localhost:99/self/index.php");

$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "self";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$self = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 
//get data
require_once('connecttodatabase.php'); 
mysql_select_db($database, $self);

//build query
$query = 
  "SELECT 
  name, 
  desc, 
  cat, 
  price 
  FROM itmes";

$rsPackages = mysql_query($query, $self) or 
  die(mysql_error());

$arRows = array();
while ($row_rsPackages = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPackages)) {
  array_push($arRows, $row_rsPackages);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arRows);


?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you used command DESC in selection, which throws an Exception. Use special symbols to prevent these problems:

```
`something`
```

So your code will have this form:

```
$query = 
  "SELECT 
  `name`, 
  `desc`, 
  `cat`, 
  `price` 
  FROM `itmes`";
```

and it should be working.